# Sorting MultiDimentional NSMutableArray in Ascending Order Objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

I am trying to sort this NSMutableArray(with dictionary objects) in ascending order with the key @"Channel" (there are multiple channel entries, i have just shortened it for readability):

I tried to sort using:

```
NSSortDescriptor *channelDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Channel" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
NSArray *descriptors = @[channelDescriptor];
[self.tempArrayDuplicateDataForAppWatch sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Data:

```
{
    Airings =     (
                {
            AiringTime = "2015-08-24T19:00:00Z";
            AiringType = Unknown;
            CC = 1;
            Category = Movie;
            Color = Color;
            DSS = 0;
            DVS = 0;
            Dolby = 0;
            Duration = 120;
            HD = 0;
            HDLevel = "HD Level Unknown";
            LetterBox = 0;
            MovieRating = R;
            ProgramId = 20306212;
            SAP = 0;
            Sports = 0;
            Stereo = 1;
            Subcategory = horror;
            TVRating = "TV-MA";
            Title = Chernobyl;
        }
    );
    CallLetters = Syfy;
    Channel = 151;
    ChannelImages =     (
                {
            AspectRatio = "109:79";
            ImageCaption = "Source logo";
            ImageCredit = Syfy;
            ImageCreditDisplay = false;
            ImageExpiryDateTime = "<null>";
            ImageFormat = jpg;
            ImageFormatId = 144;
            ImageHorizontalResolution = 720;
            ImageId = 74975320;
            ImageOwner = Syfy;
            ImageTitle = Syfy;
            ImageType = "Station Logo";
            ImageUrl = ;
            ImageVerticalResolution = 521;
            LastUpdate = "2014-07-11T22:05:13Z";
            ObjectId = 1232;
            ObjectName = "Syfy (East)";
            ObjectType = Source;
            ParentImageId = 16795667;
        }
    );
    ChannelSchedules =     (
    );
    DisplayName = Syfy;
    IconAvailable = 0;
    IsChannelOverride = 0;
    Order = 1510647;
    ParentNetworkId = 0;
    ServiceId = 82368;
    SourceAttributeTypes = "";
    SourceAttributes = 0;
    SourceId = 1232;
    SourceLongName = "Syfy (East)";
    SourceType = Basic;
    Type = "24-Hours";
},
{
    Airings =     (
                {
            AiringTime = "2015-08-24T19:00:00Z";
            AiringType = Repeat;
            CC = 1;
            Category = Other;
            Color = Color;
            DSS = 0;
            DVS = 0;
            Dolby = 0;
            Duration = 30;
            HD = 0;
            HDLevel = "HD Level Unknown";
            LetterBox = 0;
            ProgramId = 26463608;
            SAP = 0;
            SeriesId = 24828094;
            Sports = 0;
            Stereo = 1;
            Subcategory = "game show";
            TVRating = None;
            Title = "Celebrity Game";
        },
                {
            AiringTime = "2015-08-24T19:30:00Z";
            AiringType = Repeat;
            CC = 1;
            Category = Other;
            Color = Color;
            DSS = 0;
            DVS = 0;
            Dolby = 0;
            Duration = 30;
            HD = 0;
            HDLevel = "HD Level Unknown";
            LetterBox = 0;
            ProgramId = 26332661;
            SAP = 0;
            SeriesId = 24828094;
            Sports = 0;
            Stereo = 1;
            Subcategory = "game show";
            TVRating = None;
            Title = "Celebrity Game";
        },
                {
            AiringTime = "2015-08-24T20:00:00Z";
            AiringType = Repeat;
            CC = 1;
            Category = Other;
            Color = Color;
            DSS = 0;
            DVS = 0;
            Dolby = 0;
            Duration = 30;
            HD = 0;
            HDLevel = "HD Level Unknown";
            LetterBox = 0;
            ProgramId = 1055967;
            SAP = 0;
            Sports = 0;
            Stereo = 0;
            Subcategory = "game show";
            TVRating = "TV-PG";
            Title = "Family Feud";
        },
                {
            AiringTime = "2015-08-24T20:30:00Z";
            AiringType = Repeat;
            CC = 1;
            Category = Other;
            Color = Color;
            DSS = 0;
            DVS = 0;
            Dolby = 0;
            Duration = 30;
            HD = 0;
            HDLevel = "HD Level Unknown";
            LetterBox = 0;
            ProgramId = 1055967;
            SAP = 0;
            Sports = 0;
            Stereo = 0;
            Subcategory = "game show";
            TVRating = "TV-PG";
            Title = "Family Feud";
        }
    );
    CallLetters = WDAF;
    Channel = 4;
    ChannelImages =     (
                {
            AspectRatio = "23:9";
            ImageCaption = "92x36;darklight";
            ImageCreditDisplay = false;
            ImageExpiryDateTime = "<null>";
            ImageFormat = jpg;
            ImageFormatId = 97;
            ImageHorizontalResolution = 800;
            ImageId = 4065300;
            ImageTitle = FOX;
            ImageType = "Station Logo";
            ImageUrl = ;
            ImageVerticalResolution = 313;
            LastUpdate = "2015-06-22T16:50:52Z";
            ObjectId = 134;
            ObjectName = WDAF;
            ObjectType = Source;
            ParentImageId = 16814381;
        }
    );
    ChannelSchedules =     (
    );
    DisplayName = WDAF;
    IconAvailable = 1;
    IsChannelOverride = 0;
    Order = 40002;
    ParentNetworkId = 3;
    ServiceId = 82368;
    SourceAttributeTypes = "";
    SourceAttributes = 0;
    SourceId = 134;
    SourceLongName = WDAF;
    SourceType = Broadcast;
    Type = "24-Hours";
}
```

I realize that the @"Channel" value is in a string format, and i can't use "compare:" i was wondering if there was a better way to this. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: What makes you think the Channel value is a string? You can't tell just from the output you posted. Update your question with your attempt to do the sorting.

Comment: Did you examine at all the spec for NSMutableArray??

Comment: This is what i tried to use:NSSortDescriptor *channelDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Channel" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSArray *descriptors = @[channelDescriptor];
    [self.tempArrayDuplicateDataForAppWatch sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];

Comment: You've now updated your question with code similar to the posted answer. What was the result? Did it work or not?

Comment: I had tried that method before i posted. It didn't work. I got an error: ""Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSSortDescriptor' to parameter of type NSArray""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again Thanks for your help and advice. I finally figured out why the NSSortDescriptor was not working. The value of @"Channel" was a string so the sort wouldn't work correctly. I had to extract each Dictionary from the NSMutableArray one by one, and change the value of @"Channel" to NSNumber/NSDecimalNumber, then replace the old string value with the new value. Then i sorted with NSSortDescriptor and it worked.

Here is the sample code:

```
for (int i=0; i<[unsortedNSMutableArray count]; i++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempChannelInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        tempChannelInfo = unsortedNSMutableArray[i];
        NSString *tempChannelString = tempChannelInfo[@"Channel"];
        NSNumber *convertedChannel = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:tempChannelString];
        [tempChannelInfo setObject:convertedChannel forKey:@"Channel"];
        [unsortedNSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tempChannelInfo];
    }
```

Then i Sorted:

```
NSSortDescriptor *channelDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Channel" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSArray *descriptors = @[channelDescriptor];
    [unsortedNSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Thanks again for all your help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

**For sorting array which having NSArray of dictionary having values of a key is as follow.**

```
brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Channel" ascending:YES];
sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

I pulled the code from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE. Also, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html comes into play, in that `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors`: will send a `valueForKey`: to each element in myArray, and then use standard comparators to sort the returned values.

Comment: How does this code sort an array of dictionary on the value of the "Channel" key?

Comment: OK, now the 3rd bit of code is good. It's just a repeat of the first bit of code but with the proper key. But the 2nd bit of code won't work for this job - at least without completely changing the code inside the block.

Comment: @rmaddy  yes you are right so check now updated answer .

Comment: Just get rid of the 1st bit of code. it's pointless due to the more relevant 2nd bit of code.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt help!. The "myArray" in the code you provided above is actually an NSMutableArray in my code. I get this error when i try your approach: "Incompatible pointer types sending  'NSSortDescriptor' to parameter of type NSArray"

Comment: @user2378344  this link may help you for that https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html